Как сделать чтобы после перезапуска программы не подгружалась одна переменная из .ini файла в QSettings
Есть приложение, в нём при нажатии на кнопку btnSet, некоторые параметры, сохраняются в .ini файл и подгружаются, после перезапуска, из него.



Но после перезапуска программы подгружается так же последнее введенное число в QLineEdit, после перезапуска я ничего не вводил и не нажимал, программа автоматически подгрузила последнее введнное число из SummerInput

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа запоминала только Пропорции SummerProportionsCity и Нормы расхода SummerRatesCity, подскажите как переписать код, чтобы добиться желаемого результата?
main.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PySide6.QtCore import QSettings
from design import Ui_root
sys.argv += ['-platform', 'windows:darkmode=1']

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_root):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # setting
        self.btnSet.clicked.connect(self.saveSettings)
        self.btnSet.setShortcut(QApplication.translate("root", u"Ctrl+S", None))
        # property
        self.propCity = None
        self.propHighway = None
        self.normCity = None
        self.normHighway = None
        self.propCityWinter = None
        self.normCityWinter = None
        self.propHighwayWinter = None
        self.normHighwayWinter = None
        # function
        self.btnSummer.clicked.connect(self.funcSummer)
        self.btnWinter.clicked.connect(self.funcWinter)
        # menubar
        self.btnAbout.clicked.connect(self.funcAbout)
        self.btnHelp.clicked.connect(self.funcHelp)
        self.btnGear.setCheckable(True)
        self.btnGear.clicked.connect(self.funcGear)
        # summer
        self.applyPropCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropCitySummer)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormCitySummer)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwaySummer)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwaySummer)
        # winter
        self.applyPropCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropCityWinter)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormCityWinter)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newPropHighwayWinter)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.clicked.connect(self.newNormHighwayWinter)
        self.loadSettings()
    # settings
    def loadSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.inputSummer.setText(settings.value('SummerInput', ""))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setText(settings.value('SummerProportionsCity', ""))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setText(settings.value('SummerProportionsHighway', ""))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setText(settings.value('SummerRatesCity', ""))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setText(settings.value('SummerRatesHighway', ""))
        if self.inputPropCitySummer.text(): self.applyPropCitySummer.click()
        if self.inputNormCitySummer.text(): self.applyNormCitySummer.click()
        if self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text(): self.applyPropHighwaySummer.click()
        if self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text(): self.applyNormHighwaySummer.click()
        self.inputWinter.setText(settings.value('WinterInput', ""))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setText(settings.value('WinterProportionsCity', ""))
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setText(settings.value('WinterProportionsHighway', ""))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setText(settings.value('WinterRatesCity', ""))
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setText(settings.value('WinterRatesHighway', ""))
        if self.inputPropCityWinter.text(): self.applyPropCityWinter.click()
        if self.inputNormCityWinter.text(): self.applyNormCityWinter.click()
        if self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text(): self.applyPropHighwayWinter.click()
        if self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text(): self.applyNormHighwayWinter.click()

    def saveSettings(self):
        settings = QSettings("settings.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue("SummerInput", self.inputSummer.text())
        settings.setValue("SummerProportionsCity", self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("SummerProportionsHighway", self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("SummerRatesCity", self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("SummerRatesHighway", self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
        settings.setValue("WinterInput", self.inputWinter.text())
        settings.setValue("WinterProportionsCity", self.inputPropCityWinter.text())
        settings.setValue("WinterProportionsHighway", self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text())
        settings.setValue("WinterRatesCity", self.inputNormCityWinter.text())
        settings.setValue("WinterRatesHighway", self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text())
        msg = QMessageBox.information(self, "Настройки", f"Новые параметры сохранены.")

    def funcSummer(self):
        try:
            if self.propCity:
                propCity = self.propCity
            else:
                propCity = 0.3
            if self.normCity:
                normCity = self.normCity
            else:
                normCity = 11.5
            if self.propHighway:
                propHighway = self.propHighway
            else:
                propHighway = 0.7
            if self.normHighway:
                normHighway = self.normHighway
            else:
                normHighway = 8.5

            inSummer = float(self.inputSummer.text())
            roadCity = round(propCity * inSummer, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway, 2)
            totalSummer = round((propCity * inSummer / 100 * normCity) +
                                (propHighway * inSummer / 100 * normHighway), 2)

            self.outSummer.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalSummer} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCity} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighway} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCity}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighway}'
            )

        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propCity = float(self.inputPropCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так."
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormCitySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normCity = float(self.inputNormCitySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()

        except Exception as e:

            self.normCity = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так."
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.propHighway = float(self.inputPropHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()

        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так."
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormHighwaySummer(self):
        try:
            self.normHighway = float(self.inputNormHighwaySummer.text())
            self.funcSummer()

        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighway = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так."
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def funcWinter(self):

        try:
            if self.propCityWinter:
                propCityWinter = self.propCityWinter
            else:
                propCityWinter = 0.3
            if self.normCityWinter:
                normCityWinter = self.normCityWinter
            else:
                normCityWinter = 13.8
            if self.propHighwayWinter:
                propHighwayWinter = self.propHighwayWinter
            else:
                propHighwayWinter = 0.7
            if self.normHighwayWinter:
                normHighwayWinter = self.normHighwayWinter
            else:
                normHighwayWinter = 10.2

            inWinter = float(self.inputWinter.text())
            roadCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter, 2)
            roadHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter, 2)
            resultCity = round(propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter, 2)
            resultHighway = round(propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter, 2)
            totalWinter = round((propCityWinter * inWinter / 100 * normCityWinter) +
                                (propHighwayWinter * inWinter / 100 * normHighwayWinter), 2)

            self.outWinter.setText(
                f' Ваш расход составил {totalWinter} литров\n\n'
                f' Детальная информация \n'
                f' Пробег по городу {roadCity} км \n'
                f' Расход по городу {resultCity} литров\n'
                f' Пробег по трассе {roadHighway} км \n'
                f' Расход по трассе {resultHighway} литров\n\n'
                f' Нормы расхода\n'
                f' Город {normCityWinter} на 100 км\n'
                f' Трасса {normHighwayWinter} на 100 км\n\n'
                f' Пропорции\n'
                f' Коэф. по городу {propCityWinter}\n'
                f' Коэф. по трассе {propHighwayWinter}'
            )

        except Exception as e:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self, 'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так. \n"
                                  f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propCityWinter = float(self.inputPropCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()

        except Exception as e:
            self.propCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormCityWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normCityWinter = float(self.inputNormCityWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normCityWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание', f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                            f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newPropHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.propHighwayWinter = float(self.inputPropHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.propHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def newNormHighwayWinter(self):
        try:
            self.normHighwayWinter = float(self.inputNormHighwayWinter.text())
            self.funcWinter()
        except Exception as e:
            self.normHighwayWinter = None
            msg = QMessageBox.information(
                self,
                'Внимание',
                f"Что-то пошло не так.\n"
                f"Проверьте исходные данные.")

    def funcGear(self):
        if self.btnGear.isChecked():
            self.resize(560, 670)
        else:
            self.resize(560, 450)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

design.py
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,mQSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor, QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon, QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter, QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QTabWidget, QWidget)
import files_rc

class Ui_root(object):
    def setupUi(self, root):
        if not root.objectName():
            root.setObjectName(u"root")
        root.resize(560, 450)
        root.setMinimumSize(QSize(560, 450))
        root.setMaximumSize(QSize(560, 670))
        root.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        root.setMouseTracking(False)
        icon = QIcon()
        icon.addFile(u":/icon/icon.ico", QSize(), QIcon.Normal, QIcon.Off)
        root.setWindowIcon(icon)
        root.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        root.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        root.setStyleSheet(u"")
        root.setDocumentMode(False)
        root.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.grid_w = QWidget(root)
        self.grid_w.setObjectName(u"grid_w")
        self.inputSummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputSummer.setObjectName(u"inputSummer")
        self.inputSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputSummer.setLayoutDirection(Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.inputSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.inputSummer.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.inputSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.inputSummer.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.outSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outSummer.setObjectName(u"outSummer")
        self.outSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outSummer.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 230);")
        self.outSummer.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.btnSummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSummer.setObjectName(u"btnSummer")
        self.btnSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnSummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnSummer.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnSummer.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.btnWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnWinter.setObjectName(u"btnWinter")
        self.btnWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 80, 241, 41))
        self.btnWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.outWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.outWinter.setObjectName(u"outWinter")
        self.outWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 130, 241, 281))
        self.outWinter.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);")
        self.outWinter.setInputMethodHints(Qt.ImhNone)
        self.outWinter.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading | Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.inputWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputWinter.setObjectName(u"inputWinter")
        self.inputWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 40, 241, 31))
        self.inputWinter.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.inputWinter.setMaxLength(10)
        self.label_s = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.label_s.setObjectName(u"label_s")
        self.label_s.setGeometry(QRect(20, 10, 241, 21))
        self.label_s.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.lable_w = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.lable_w.setObjectName(u"lable_w")
        self.lable_w.setGeometry(QRect(300, 10, 241, 21))
        self.btnAbout = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnAbout.setObjectName(u"btnAbout")
        self.btnAbout.setGeometry(QRect(20, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnAbout.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnAbout.setStyleSheet(u"")
        self.btnHelp = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnHelp.setObjectName(u"btnHelp")
        self.btnHelp.setGeometry(QRect(53, 417, 29, 28))
        self.btnHelp.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnHelp.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnHelp.setFlat(False)
        self.btnSet = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnSet.setObjectName(u"btnSet")
        self.btnSet.setGeometry(QRect(476, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnSet.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.btnGear = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.btnGear.setObjectName(u"btnGear")
        self.btnGear.setGeometry(QRect(510, 417, 30, 28))
        self.btnGear.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelPropSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropSummer.setObjectName(u"labelPropSummer")
        self.labelPropSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 470, 71, 16))
        self.applyPropCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropCitySummer")
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelNormSummer = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormSummer.setObjectName(u"labelNormSummer")
        self.labelNormSummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 570, 91, 16))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwaySummer")
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwaySummer")
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormCitySummer = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"applyNormCitySummer")
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(180, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormCityWinter")
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 590, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyNormHighwayWinter")
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 630, 81, 31))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropCityWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropCityWinter")
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 490, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter = QPushButton(self.grid_w)
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"applyPropHighwayWinter")
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(460, 530, 81, 31))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.labelPropWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelPropWinter.setObjectName(u"labelPropWinter")
        self.labelPropWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 470, 71, 16))
        self.labelNormWinter = QLabel(self.grid_w)
        self.labelNormWinter.setObjectName(u"labelNormWinter")
        self.labelNormWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 570, 91, 16))
        self.inputPropCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropCitySummer")
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 491, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwaySummer")
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropCityWinter")
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 490, 151, 31))
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"inputPropHighwayWInter")
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 530, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCitySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormCitySummer")
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwaySummer")
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setGeometry(QRect(20, 630, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormCityWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormCityWinter")
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 590, 151, 31))
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter = QLineEdit(self.grid_w)
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setObjectName(u"inputNormHighwayWInter")
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setGeometry(QRect(300, 630, 151, 31))
        root.setCentralWidget(self.grid_w)
        self.retranslateUi(root)
        self.btnHelp.setDefault(False)
        self.btnGear.setDefault(False)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(root)

    # setupUi
    def retranslateUi(self, root):
        root.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"BenzConfig", None))
        self.inputSummer.setInputMask("")
        self.inputSummer.setText("")
        self.inputSummer.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.outSummer.setText("")
        self.btnSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnSummer.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Return", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0420\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c", None))
        #if QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.btnWinter.setShortcut(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"Tab", None))
        #endif // QT_CONFIG(shortcut)
        self.outWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setText("")
        self.inputWinter.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                       u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435",
                                                                       None))
        self.label_s.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041b\u0435\u0442\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.lable_w.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0417\u0438\u043c\u043d\u0438\u0439", None))
        self.btnAbout.setText("")
        self.btnHelp.setText("")
        self.btnGear.setText("")
        self.labelPropSummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.applyPropCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelNormSummer.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.applyNormHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwaySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCitySummer.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyNormHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropCityWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.applyPropHighwayWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
        self.labelPropWinter.setText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0446\u0438\u0438", None))
        self.labelNormWinter.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("root",
                                                                u"\u041d\u043e\u0440\u043c\u044b \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0430",
                                                                None))
        self.inputPropCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputPropCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputPropHighwayWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCitySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwaySummer.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
        self.inputNormCityWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434", None))
        self.inputNormHighwayWinter.setPlaceholderText(
            QCoreApplication.translate("root", u"\u0422\u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u0430", None))
    # retranslateUi


Так просто уберите строки settings.setValue("SummerInput", self.inputSummer.text()) из saveSettings и self.inputSummer.setText(settings.value('SummerInput', "")) из loadSettings... И другие которые вам не нужны. Программа-то ваша? )

Vadim Chekaev, если вам не надо что-то сохранять - удалите это как вам написал @AlexanderChernin . Если вам не надо делать автоматический расчет, то уберите из метода load_settings() все строк if self.inputPropCitySummer.text(): self.applyPropCitySummer.click(). Если вы хотите сделать что-то другое - то лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

@ AlexanderChernin спасибо
